# Bug in MathTime Pro2 - Is there a workaround?

Tags: mtpro

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\begin{document}

\morphedbraces

\begin{equation*}
  \left\{ \right\} \left\{ \vbox to 20pt{} \right\} \left\{ \vbox to 30pt{} \right\}
  \left\{ \vbox to 40pt{} \right\}
\end{equation*}    
\end{document}
```

gives me this:

[image: Bug in MathTime Pro2]

The bug is triggered by `\morphedbraces` (uncomment it, and everything is fine).

Is there a way to fix this?

#### Update

PcTex finally confirmed that this is a bug. Some updated files did not make it into their package. Updated packages will be posted on their website soon.

Comment: Since you know it is a bug, you should report it to the package maintainer. [It was agreed (link)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2625/11002) that bug reports are not so good questions for this site.

Comment: @tohecz This is more of Case 3 that is discussed in the answer you linked, i.e., I am asking for a workaround.

Comment: What is the version of your package?  The one on CTAN specifically mentions fixing such a bug :`\ProvidesPackage{mtpro2}
 [2009/4/27 v2.3
 MathTimePro II - added arc accents
 MathTimePro II - fixed rbrace problem with straightbraces and morphedbraces options`

Comment: @AndrewSwann This is exactly the version I have.

Comment: @mafp I changed the title; you *ask* for a workaround, don't you? Maybe it all reduces to a language problem. But I recommend avoiding "want": nobody here is paid for giving help.

Comment: @AndrewSwann The problem was apparently fixed in the package (`.sty`), but not in the metric file. `:(`

Comment: @egreg You are right, I did not mean "want" as in "to demand", but as in "to wish", or "to need". Sorry if someone understood that differently.

Comment: @Speravir I did so. A fix *is* a workaround, right? Next time, read more carefully ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a couple of problems in the metric file used for the extended symbols, `mt2exa.tfm`. A `NEXTLARGER` command points to an incorrect character and another one is missing.

So this is definitely a bug; please, report it to the maintainers of the MTPro package and remember to announce when the bug is solved by adding the information to your question.

### Workaround

If you are on a Unix system, create a work directory, say `~/fixmt2`; I assume a Bash shell.

```
cd ~/fixmt2
tftopl mt2exa > mt2exa.pl
nano mt2exa.pl
```

(use the editor you wish, instead of `nano`)

Find the string `CHARACTER O 266` and change

```
(CHARACTER O 266
   (CHARWD R 0.646)
   (CHARHT R 0.6615)
   )
```

into

```
(CHARACTER O 266
   (CHARWD R 0.646)
   (CHARHT R 0.6615)
   (NEXTLARGER O 270)
   )
```

In the next entry

```
(CHARACTER O 267
   (CHARWD R 0.646)
   (CHARHT R 0.6615)
   (NEXTLARGER O 270)
   )
```

change `270` into `271` to obtain

```
(CHARACTER O 267
   (CHARWD R 0.646)
   (CHARHT R 0.6615)
   (NEXTLARGER O 271)
   )
```

Save the file and exit the text editor. Now run the shell command

```
kpsewhich mt2exa.tfm
```

that will answer something like

```
/usr/local/texlive/2012/../texmf-local/fonts/tfm/pctex/mtpro2/mt2exa.tfm
```

Issue

```
sudo mv /usr/local/texlive/2012/../texmf-local/fonts/tfm/pctex/mtpro2/mt2exa.tfm{,~}
```

so as to save a copy of the old `tfm` file (use the location you get for the file). Then do

```
pltotf mt2exa
```

and

```
sudo mv mt2exa.tfm /usr/local/texlive/2012/../texmf-local/fonts/tfm/pctex/mtpro2/
```

Now, running your file through LaTeX should give

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is a remarkably good fix! I've never used the `morphedbraces` option of the `mtpro2` package before, but I've run your fix/workaround on my copy of the package, just so that I have it handy if and when I have a need for this option.

Comment: Great solution! Works perfectly. I sent a message to PCTex, informing them about the problem (and including a link back here to sx.tx).

Comment: has anyone mailed pctex, inc?  a link to this answer would probably help them to get the package mended rather quickly.

Comment: @wasteofspace: mafp did and has already got a response, see the edit in the question. About CTAN they seem to have said nothing.