# Bug of the mtpro2 package with morphedbraces and straightbraces options?

Tags: mtpro

I have installed the complete mtpro2, and the `mtpro2.sty` reads:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1997/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mtpro2}
 [2009/4/27 v2.3
 MathTimePro II - added arc accents
 MathTimePro II - fixed rbrace problem with straightbraces and morphedbraces options
 MathTimePro II - fix bug with z = \backslash widetilde{\backslash sum_{x }}%
 MathTimePro II v2 font support (PCTeX/WaS)%
 MathTimePro II v2.1a  Allowed alternate form of I in Math Script Fonts (MS)%
]
```

However, when I use the package with `morphedbraces` option as follows:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[morphedbraces]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}

\[
\left\{\right\} \quad \Bigl\{\Bigr\} \quad
\left\{\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \end{matrix} \right\} \quad
\left\{\frac12\right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

It produces a strange result:
[image]

And if I use the `straightbraces` option, anomaly happens again:
[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87538/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried the method given by egreg, but it didn’t work.